# Selenium - NoSuchElementException error checking

Tags: java, selenium, exception, selenium-webdriver

At the end of every test case I am checking to see if an error is present by calling the following code. The problem I have is even if an error is not present the code will throw a `NoSuchElementException` and will fail the test case.  If the error is present the test case will pass.

How can I modify my code so if an error is not present the test will pass and if an error is present the test case will fail.

```
public static void chk_ErrorIsNotEnabled()
{
    try
    {
        element = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_Content_ulErrorList"));
        if(element.getText().equals(""))
        {
            Log.info("Warning error is not dispayed." ); // The test should pass if element is not found
        }
        else
        {
            Log.error("Warning error is dispayed when it shouldnt be.");
        } //The test should fail if element is found
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e){}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the element is not present and `selenium` throws `NoSuchElement` exceptions which eventually catch the `catch` block while your code expect an element with this id `ctl00_Content_ulErrorList`. You cannot get text on an element which does not exist.

A good test will be something like the following:
Notice the `findElements()` here. It should find the `size` of the elements with error list. If that is more than `0` you know that errored out and test should fail

```
if(driver.findElements(By.id("ctl00_Content_ulErrorList")).size() > 0){
    Log.error("Warning error is dispayed when it shouldnt be.");
}else{
    //pass
    Log.info("Warning error is not dispayed." ); // The test should pass if element is not found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also  create  one method for navigation  by ID which  you will  reuse  every time  and   simple  assertion  should solve your  problem

```
private WebElement currentElement;    

public boolean navigateToElementById(String id) {
    try {
        currentElement = currentElement.findElement(By.id(id));
    } catch (NoSuchElementException nsee) {
        logger.warn("navigateToElementById : Element not found with id  : "
                + id);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

An then  every time in you test  you could  use :

```
assertTrue(navigateToElementById("your id"));
```