# Asserting Element Not Present Using ExpectedConditions Class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get into the practice of utilizing the ExpectedConditions class to do my Selenium related assertions, but I'm having trouble finding the de facto best practice for asserting a given element is not present.  I'm trying to use something like this ...

```
Assert.assertFalse(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(myXpath)).apply(driver1));
```

But this won't compile of course because `presenceOfElementLocated` returns a WebElement instead of a boolean, which I'm finding frustrating.  What do you recommend as the best practice for accomplishing what I'm going for?

**EDIT:** The accepted answer to the question converted to Java ...

```
public static boolean elementXpathPresent(WebDriver driver,String elementXpath) {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(elementXpath)));
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        return false;
    }   
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, using `ExpectedConditions` will eventually throw `NoSuchElementException` if there is no `element` matching the selector present. In that case you probably want to use try catch with `ExpectedConditions` or simply use `findElements()` and `size()` to see if it finds any elements at all. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28347227/selenium-nosuchelementexception-error-checking/28347592#28347592)

Here is another option for you. Written in C# but will be fairly easy to convert

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public bool Test()
{
    try
    {
        new WebDriverWait(Driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(
            ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.XPath("MyXpath")));
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException)
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
public void Assertion()
{
    Assert.IsTrue(Test());
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've used the whole `size()` method in the past but I've read a lot around here that ExpectedConditions are the way to go and what not so I thought I'd give it a shot.  But yeah, with it throwing an exception like that makes it bad for assertions of course.

Comment: @user2150250 see my edit. I think that's what you want

Comment: Ha yeah that seems to definitely accomplish the task at hand.  For simplicity's sake you just recommend using the `size()` method though right?

Comment: Not really. Most of the modern websites are built with some kind of `AJAX`. If you know for sure the element should not exist and you  just want to test that then yes use `size()` if you want to test the existence of the element that you know (SHOULD) exist then better to use the code above. To be honest I use the code above that's the best test in this scenario I think even though it's little time killer

Comment: Care accepting the answer if this is what you were looking for?

Comment: Sure, was just giving it a few more minutes to see if anyone else wanted to chime in.

Comment: @user2150250 This is a great question though. Thumbs up for asking. I want to see some other views on it as well. Anyway, Clever person :P Thanks anyway

Comment: It seems when I converted your method over to Java and used it in an assertion, it still threw a NoSuchElement exception rather than just returning false and having the assertion itself fail.  See edit above in my question.  Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you changing the assert to `Assert.assertFalse(elementXpathPresent(driver,"Your Xpath"));`?

Comment: Yeah except I was testing it for the case where an element SHOULD exist, so I was doing an assertTrue ... `Assert.assertTrue(elementXpathPresent(driver,myXpath));`  Either way it should be returning `true` or `false`, not an exception right?

Comment: You are right. Can you put a breakpoint and see what line is throwing error?

Comment: The exception is being thrown at the `wait.until` line

Comment: And, should catch `catch()` block. Does not it?

Comment: Ah I figured it out ... `presenceOfElementLocated` throws a `TimeoutException` when it can't find the element.  It works now.  I've changed my edit to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check that an element is not present is to use the plural form of the `findElement` function (i.e. `findElements`) and check the length of the returned list of element. If the element is not present, then the list will be of size 0.

```
Assert.assertTrue(driver.findElements(By.xpath(myXpath)).size() == 0);
```

Whether or not it makes sense to use an explicit wait for *this test* really depends on your application. Most of the time when I am checking for the absence of an element, I have an earlier tests that uses an explicit wait. For instance, if I want to check that a change to a search table empties the table, I first check that the table has finished refreshing and *then* check that it is empty. The former check needs an explicit wait, the latter check does not.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is a good way to do this (and it's the way I prefer to make assertions with Selenium). But you could also use `ExpectedConditions.not()` with `Assert.true()` to assert that elements aren't present:

```
Assert.assertTrue(
    ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath(myXpath))).apply(driver1));
```